# Qt QApplication as a member attribute for a class crashes the application

Tags: c++, qt

I am using a Qt application as a part of my project. I have multiple threads running performing various tasks and I wanted to make the GUI a separate thread too.

As an initial step I tried to move the  `QApplication` and  `MainWindow` objects from main function to a different class as member attributes. And this crashes the application.

Console just says:

> The program has unexpectedly finished.

When I debug, I see a segmentation fault on execution of `a.exec()` where `a` is a `QApplication` object.

Here's my code:

trialmain.h

```
class TrialMain
{

public:
    QApplication a;
    MainWindow w;

    TrialMain(int argc, char *argv[]);
    int run();
};
```

trialmain.cpp

```
TrialMain::TrialMain(int argc, char *argv[])
    :a(argc,argv)
{

}

int TrialMain::run()
{
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "trialmain.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    TrialMain tr(argc, argv);
    tr.run();

    return 0;
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#include <QMainWindow>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

};
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{

}
```

When I remove  `QApplication` and  `MainWindow` as member attributes and create local object variables inside `run()` the executes fine. I do not understand what brings the difference. Please help.

Comment: How do you use this `TrialMain`?

Comment: Looks ok for me, show usage of TrialMain class.

Comment: Updated with usage of TrialMain. BTW what was that -1 for. If its for not mentioning the usage of TrialMain, I thought its obvious and didn't want to make it verbose

Comment: Does the error occurs when you remove `MainWindow`?

Comment: `MainWindow` does not create any problem, no matter when it is a member attribute or even a local variable. But when `QApplication` is a local vairable for method `run()` everything works perfect, not when it is a memeber attribute

Comment: When I change `MainWindow w` to `MainWindow *w` in the header and I create the instance in run: `int TrialMain::run()
{
    w = new MainWindow;
    w->show();
    return a.exec();
}` then the program runs normally. Maybe this will help you find the answer.

Comment: My question was: can you remove `MainWindow` completely from your code and still have the same error? If so, I'm unable to reproduce your problem and consider simplifying your [mcve]. If not, include the essential parts of `MainWindow` needed to generate the error.

Comment: @eyllanesc This trick of creating main window on heap worked. But I am quiet surprised about how did this create a problem at all.

Comment: @m7913d 12 No there is no error when I completely remove the MainWindow but obviously I wouldn't get my application running. So the actual problem was with MainWindow as a member attribute. Not sure why

Comment: Is this a minimal version, i.e. do you need the ui/button to reproduce your problem. See [mcve].

Comment: Uh sorry for that. I do not need a button to reproduce the error, neither the ui element.